# How can one see the number of reopen votes that were cast and that haven't expired yet on a question that is now locked?

Tags: support, vote-to-reopen, locked-questions

Example of a locked question: [What do the red dashed lines mean in Google Maps?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/171606/18147)

How can one see the number of reopen votes that were cast and that haven't expired yet on a question that is now locked?

Assume that one has enough points to view the number of reopen votes on a regular non-locked question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the "Retrieve close, reopen and delete votes" userscript written by [Double-Beep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/435726/double-beep).

[Github](https://github.com/double-beep/my-userscripts/blob/master/retrieveDVCV.user.js) ([direct install](https://github.com/double-beep/my-userscripts/raw/master/retrieveDVCV.user.js)).

Using this method, you do not need enough reputation to view reopen votes in the traditional way.

That question currently has one unexpired reopen vote.